# how to use source files that are not in current directory in makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

I'm new to C, sorry if my question is basic, below is my makefile:

```
src = $(wildcard *.c)
obj = $(src:.c=.o)

LDFLAGS = -pthread

prog: $(obj)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(obj) prog
```

but I have source files(let's `myfunc.c`) in other directory. I don't want to copy `myfunc.c` to every project then compile and link it, I only want to use a single source from that directory, how can I modify my makefile to reflect this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must tell Make two new things: That `myfunc.o` is needed, and where to find `myfunc.c`. (I'll assume `some/dir/myfunc.c`.)

There is more than one way to do it. A beginner should learn the simple way:

```
obj = $(src:.c=.o) myfunc.o

myfunc.o: some/dir/myfunc.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Once you understand that, you can use [vpath](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search) instead:

```
obj = $(src:.c=.o) myfunc.o

vpath %.c some/dir
```